# Тире, запятая или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Примерно такое предложение: "И самое главное — без обучения и практики стать генералом не получится".

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1. И самое главное — без обучения и практики стать генералом не получится.

Вариант 2. И самое главное, без обучения и практики стать генералом не получится.

В обоих случаях это вводное выражение (со значением основного довода), обособление с помощью запятой или тире. Авторский вариант с тире соответствует увеличенной паузе.

Примеры из Нацкоруса:

а) Вводные выражения: И самое главное, многие почтовые серверы не поддерживают стандарт. И самое главное ― ссылаются ли на него другие блогеры? И самое главное — он снят в России! И самое главное ― новогодние праздники станут для всей вашей семьи периодом, когда сбываются действительно все мечты и желания.

Б) Простое предложение: И самое главное ― постараться всё вспомнить. И самое главное―создавать привычку к платной парковке. (В роли подлежащего).

В) И самое главное: где можно почитать о смысловых нюансах при словообразовании? И самое главное: у локальной традиции появляются конкуренты. Синтаксис этого варианта определить сложнее, но тоже очень похоже на вводную конструкцию, в меньшей степени - на БСП или СПП. Используется этот вариант реже, чем другие.

Answer (score 1):

Существует вводное слово *"главное"*, а выражение *самое главное* в качестве вводного используется редко.

Часто выражение *самое главное* выполняет функцию подлежащего или сказуемого (Ср.: *И это самое главное. Самое главное - определиться...*) Поэтому после него часто ставится тире перед сказуемым, выраженным инфинитивом или существительным, а также возможно двоеточие, если *самое главное* - это первая часть бессоюзного предложения:

***И самое главное: без обучения и практики стать генералом не получится.***

В вашем предложении именно этот знак и нужен.